# Drupal login logout links

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've got the following code to show when a user is logged in and when they're not.

```
<?php
global $user;
if ($user->uid > 0) {
  echo "You are logged in as: " . $user->name . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "You are not logged in!<br>";
}
?>
```

I want to add a logout link (when logged in) & and a login link (when not logged in). Would I just use html < a > links? If so, how would I incorporate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you would just use a regular menu and add the two items.

The visibility of the items is controlled by drupals menu-system, so you won't see the login-link if you're already logged in and you won't see the logout-link if you're not logged in.

If you want to output the links programmatically I would recommend using the ["l" function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7)

```
l($text, $path, array $options = array())
```

To check if a user is logged in you can simply use the [user_is_logged_in](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) function provided by the users module.

So your code would become

```
<?php
if( user_is_logged_in() ) {
  print l('logout', 'user/logout');
}
else {
  print l('login', 'user/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want to show the links. If it is on the same page/piece of code, just go ahead and echo them:

```
<?php
global $user;
if ($user->uid > 0) {
   echo "You are logged in as: " . $user->name . "<br>";
   echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
} else {
   echo "You are not logged in!<br>";
   echo "<a href=\"login.php\">Login</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You should use the `l()` function for making links rather than writing the html yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the url function of Drupal core as below

```
<?php
global $user;
if ($user->uid > 0) {
  echo '<a href="'.url('user/logout').'">Logout </a>';
} else {
  echo '<a href="'.url('user/login').'">Logout </a>';
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: You should use the `l()` function for making links rather than writing the html yourself.